# Searching from within a list of values in SQL, and keeping this list separate

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to do broadly the following in Databricks.

SELECT
CASE WHEN work_centre IN ("wc1", "wc2"...etc) THEN "result"
FROM example

I would like to store the above values in a separate list and the SQL statement points at the whole list. This would make editing the list a lot easier. How can this be done?

I have tried searching the problem but can't define it well enough. I have a feeling that there is a functionality in PySpark somewhere where I can save it as python list or df and pass it in but need help doing this.

Comment: `col('work_centre').isin(['wc1',wc2',...)` look at isin: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.